# How to use azure b2c access token to login & register in my backend

Tags: spring-boot, azure-ad-b2c

I am designing a  backend for a mobile app.

Azure-B2C is used as an authentication server for social login. Mobile app will get access token from Azure and send to backend for registration & login and server will generate its own jwt token for future request.

How do I implement this in springboot?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/java/spring-framework/configure-spring-boot-starter-java-app-with-azure-active-directory) microsoft docs, it should help